# Running Selenium tests in Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I have recorded some simple selenium tests by Selenium IDE. Now I want to run those tests in Jenkins.
Which plugin to Jenkins do I need to do that? And how to run the tests step by step? Help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to run HTML Test Suite? or, have you exported selenium tests into other language? (e.g., java, C#, python etc.)

Answer (score 2):

you can use recorded selenium IDE script and selenium-server.jar file to run it from Jenkins
Here is steps:

1. Go to SeleniumHQ page and download Selenium Server file
       Eg: selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar
2. Repair html test suite    Use Selenium IDE to record then save as
   html test case and test suite then put them in a same folder
         eg: TestCase.html, TestSuite.html
3. In jenkins

   - Plugin Seleniumhq
   - Configure Selenium runner file
       Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Selenium Remote Control: htmlSuite Runner = path to file u have download in step 1
   - Configure Job to run
       In Build field click " Add build step" then select "seleniumhq htmlSuite Run"
       browser: *firefox   or *iexploer ....
       startURL: http://www.google.com   or ...
       suiteFile: Input absolutely path to TestSuite.html file saved in step 2
       resultFile: Input absolutely path to a file that results will be saved

Hope this help!

Comment: I created a project to do just that using 'Selenium Builder' (not IDE): https://github.com/djangofan/simple-selenium-builder-framework

Answer (score 0):

I did the same but the following error occurred:
Unable to find the HTML runner. This is normally because you have not downloaded
or made available the 'selenium-leg-rc' jar on the CLASSPATH. Your test will
not be run.
Download the Selenium HTML Runner from http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ and
use that in place of the selenium-server-standalone.jar for the simplest way of
running your HTML suite.