# Jenkins not installing Xvfb in Windows

Tags: jenkins, xvfb

I have several Selenium IDE tests which I'm trying run in Jenkins (it is running on Windows Server 2012 R2).

I've followed all the steps described at [Running Selenium tests in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896905/running-selenium-tests-in-jenkins) and the only issue I have is that Jenkins does not install Xvfb - all my attempts to use "Install automatically" option don't seem to work (I can click "apply" but Xvfb won't appear); I have also been unable to find the exe anywhere (Jenkins asks for "Directory in which to find Xvfb executable").

Is there a way to install Xvfb in Windows? I know it's very easy in Linux but I have to use Windows.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: There is no Xvfb fow windows.  Linux typically runs without display, Xvfb solves that problem by creating  a virtual display.  Windows always had a DISPLAY.  If multiple parallel runs affects the test, only solution is to create many windows nodes with single slave . Windows server editions may provide a different solution; I have not tried it.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't been able to find a solution in Windows Server that would allow that + there are some other limitations, so I'll use Jenkins in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below solution.It is worked for me in Windows 7.

1. Jenkins configuration from 'Manage Jenkins'- Provide Name as 'Default' and did not select 'Install automatically' check box.Check
   image 1. [manage Jenkins settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fcHr.png)
2. Install Xvfb plugin from Manage Plugins of Manage Jenkins - Select Xvfb plugin from available plugins list and click install.  [Plugin
   download from Jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aqMr.png)
3. Set Build Environment details in Configure window - Select 'Start Xvfb before the build, and shut it down after.' option under Build
   environment section.After click 'Advanced' button. There provide
   display name offset value as 1.

Comment: Thank you for the instructions, the Xvfb got installed. Unfortunately, it still does not work - the console output shows "System is not Unix, Xvfb will not be started".